# Defining class and methods in macro

Tags: common-lisp

I'm still quite new to Common Lisp macros.

For an abstraction over a defclass with defgeneric I thought it'd be nice to make a macro.

A complitely naive implementation looks like:

```
(defmacro defgserver (name &key call-handler cast-handler)
  "TODO: needs firther testing. Convenience macro to more easily create a new `gserver' class."
  `(progn
     (defclass ,name (gserver) ())
     (defmethod handle-call ((server ,name) message current-state)
       ,(if call-handler call-handler nil))
     (defmethod handle-cast ((server ,name) message current-state)
       ,(if cast-handler cast-handler nil))))
```

When used the error says that 'message' is not known.
I'm not sure. 'message' is the name of a parameter of `defgeneric`:

```
(defgeneric handle-call (gserver message current-state))
```

Using the macro I see a warning 'undefined variable message':

```
(defgserver foo :call-handler 
           (progn
             (print message)))
; in: DEFGSERVER FOO
;     (PRINT MESSAGE)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: COMMON-LISP-USER::MESSAGE
```

Which when used has this consequence:

```
CL-USER> (defvar *my* (make-instance 'foo))
*MY*
CL-USER> (call *my* "Foo")
 <WARN> [10:55:10] cl-gserver gserver.lisp (handle-message fun5) -
  Error condition was raised on message processing: CL-GSERVER::C: #<UNBOUND-VARIABLE MESSAGE {1002E24553}>
```

So something has to happen with `message` and/or `current-state`.
Should they be interned into the current package where the macro is used?

Manfred

Comment: Checkout `macroexpand-1` to see what kind of code you are generating with your macro...

Comment: Generally it looks like that's a package problem. The `message` in the macro needs to be the same `message` symbol in your `defgserver` form.

Comment: The macroexpand look ok to me.
And when used inside the package where the `defgeneric` is defined it works.
But not elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as mentioned, is that you are talking about different symbols.

However this is really a symptom of a more general problem: what you are trying to do is a sort of *anaphora*.  If you fixed up the package structure so this worked:

```
(defgserver foo :call-handler 
           (progn
             (print message)))
```

Then, well, what exactly is `message`?  Where did it come from, what *other* bindings exist in that scope?  Anaphora can be useful, but it also can be a source of obscure bugs like this.

So, I think a better way to do this, which avoids this problem is to say that the `*-handler` options should specify what arguments they expect.  So instead of the above form you'd write something like this:

```
(defgserver foo
  :call-handler ((server message state)
                 (print message)
                 (detonate server)))
```

So here, value of the `:call-handler-option` is the argument list and body of a function, which the macro will turn into a method specialising on the first argument.  Because the methods it creates have argument lists provided by the user of the macro there's never a problem with names, and there is no anaphora.

So, one way to do that is to do two things:

- make the default values of these options be suitable for processing into methods without any special casing;
- write a little local function in the macro which turns one of these specifications into a suitable `(defmethod ...)` form.

The second part is optional of course, but it saves a little bit of code.

In addition to this I've also done a slightly dirty trick: I've changed the macro definition so it has an `&body` option, the value of which is ignored.  The only reason I've done this is to help my editor indent it better.

So, here's a revised version:

```
(defmacro defgserver (name &body forms &key 
                           (call-handler '((server message current-state)
                                           (declare (ignorable 
                                                     server message current-state))
                                           nil))
                           (cast-handler '((server message current-state)
                                           (declare (ignorable 
                                                     server message current-state))
                                           nil)))
  "TODO: needs firther testing. Convenience macro to more easily
create a new `gserver' class."
  (declare (ignorable forms))
  (flet ((write-method (mname mform)
           (destructuring-bind (args &body decls/forms) mform
             `(defmethod ,mname ((,(first args) ,name) ,@(rest args))
               ,@decls/forms))))
    `(progn
       (defclass ,name (gserver) ())
       ,(write-method 'handle-call call-handler)
       ,(write-method 'handle-cast cast-handler))))
```

And now

```
(defgserver foo
  :call-handler ((server message state)
                 (print message)
                 (detonate server)))
```

Expands to

```
(progn
  (defclass foo (gserver) nil)
  (defmethod handle-call ((server foo) message state)
    (print message)
    (detonate server))
  (defmethod handle-cast ((server foo) message current-state)
    (declare (ignorable server message current-state))
    nil))
```

Comment: This is a pretty sophisticated macro.
I'll need a bit to understand how it works.
Thanks